# Storing a MySQL object with variables based on "Type"

Tags: mysql, relational-database

got a quick question on how best to store some data in a MySQL database.

**Table - Asset**

ID
Name
Description
Model Number

**Table - Asset Type**

ID
Name

Each of the assets will have an asset type, and based on that type, it will have additional fields (e.g a HP ProDesk might have a type of Workstation, and based on that type it will also have RAM and CPU fields). How would it be best to store this data?

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would create table per type. It's not practical to have some generic tables, that can hold records, which have varying set of properties (which would map to varying set of columns).

So, I'd have for example table `Workstation` with appropriate columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to have an entity relationship diagram to briefly picture out how the objects related between each other. For example, **one** asset can only have **one** type and **one** type can belong to **many** different assets, which means that the relationship for  asset and asset type is **one to many** relationship.

**Asset Type (one) - Asset (many)**

Since this is a one to many relationship, a foreign key column should be placed in the "many" side, which is the asset table.

> based on that type it will also have RAM and CPU fields

As for this, I may suggest that you build a table for each type of asset and inherited from the *asset* table. For example, workstations and monitor are assets. Thus your database should look like this.

**TABLE: Asset Type**
Asset_Type_Id (PK)
Asset_Type_Name

**TABLE: Asset**
Asset_Id (PK)
Asset_Name
Asset_Description
Asset_Model_Number
Asset_Type_Id (FK reference **Asset Type**)

**TABLE: Workstation**
WorkStation_Id (PK, FK reference **Asset**)
WorkStation_Name
CPU
GPU

**TABLE: Monitor**
Monitor_Id (PK, FK reference **Asset**)
Monitor_Name
Resolution